# how to sort tableview by an NSDate input (Formatted to MMM yyyy)

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hello I am relatively new to iOS development(Sorry in advance if this question has already been addressed) and I have been this sub-module in this app where the user has to enter daily numerical data, the list is then displayed in a tableview. The thing is I am trying to sort by a NSdate variable "inputDate" in a format of MMMM yyyy (example: section named: February 2013). But, even if a value was entered in a same month it doesnt group them in the same sections(see link at the end for illustration)

Here are sections of the code which seems to be relevant to the problem:

```
  //The Fetch result controller

  - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create and configure a fetch request with the PVMessWert entity.


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PVMessWert" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array.

    NSSortDescriptor *datumsort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"inputDate" ascending:NO];


    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:datumsort, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.


    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"inputDate" cacheName:@"Root"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;



    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

then: titleForHeaderInSection:

```
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]         objectAtIndex:section];

 NSArray *objects = [sectionInfo objects];
 NSManagedObject *managedObject = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
NSDate *headerDate = (NSDate *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"inputDate"];
NSString *headerTitle = [formatter stringFromDate:headerDate];

 return headerTitle;
```

}

Then, Dateformatter function:

```
 - (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    if (dateFormatter == nil) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
       [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

And for illustration of the problem a small screenshot of detailledListView

URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Kvz.png

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're sorting the FRC on `dailyvalue`, but you don't show what that is or appear to use it anywhere else...

Comment: ah sorry,i was testing to sort by the entered "dailyvalue" when by "inputData" didnt work, the problem is still there( it should be by managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"inputData" cacheName:@"Root"];)  i already had it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello(Sorry for writing too much on the matter).

I was able to solve the issue by adding a  string attribute(core data) to store converted NSDates to NSString :

```
- (NSString *)dateToString {

   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *headerDate = (NSDate *)[self valueForKey:@"inputDate"];
    NSString *headerTitle = [formatter stringFromDate:headerDate];
    return headerTitle;
}
```

and fetch request    where this dateToString is the key path.

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateToString" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

Hope this will be useful to others in same situation

Answer (score 0):

The `sectionNameKeyPath` should be a string, not a date. Generally, you would add a transient attribute to your entity and set that to the string version of your section identifiers (`inputDate` in this case). The transient value would be the string you're currently using as `headerTitle` and can be generated in just the same way. You can trigger it using KVO or when the managed object is saved.

Comment: So the reason why your entries all show up in different sections is because it is comparing the NSDate object, not the string. So even though the string values of all the dates are the same, the date values are not so it puts them in different sections. As @wain said, you will have to sort by the string version not the date version.

Comment: so u mean store the date as a NString attribute and call that attribute as sectionNameKeyPath?  but will that sort by months or by alphabetic? Sorry if this sounds trivial, I do not fully grasp the solution to the issue

Comment: No, don't store a string version of the date as `sectionName`. Store the string you calculate as `headerTitle`.

Comment: Yes, that is what the FRC is going to use to do the section grouping. And you can get it back from the FRC to use as the section title in your delegate method.

Comment: Okey now I get it, but how do i call or use it programmatically?

Comment: You just create the transient attribute, set the value whenever the `inputDate` changes and set the name of the attribute as the `sectionNameKeyPath`. The FRC will do all the grouping. In the delegate method ask the FRC for `[sections[section] name]` to get the name to display.

Comment: I tried to add the attribute and modify some of the things, but i get that key error thing and "unable to find core data store" error.....Migration problems i guess. I am really knew to iOS and I tried really hard to advance as much as possible, but I cant seem to get off this section grouping problem. Can anyone please provide a sample code for the procedure. Many Thanks.